# watch src dir for changes then run npm script passing the filename and relative path

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I have a node script and I would like to run it passing the filename/path that just changed. I figured that you can watch files with nodemon or npm watch.

But I could not find anything about how to the the file that just changed to the script. Or I probably did not understand.

Anyone can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

For whoever that might have a similar problem. Here is the solution I came up with:

I have a node script upload.js. It basically log me in and upload a file using puppeteer.
package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "upload": "node upload.js"
  }
```

tasks.json:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "upload",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "upload --${file}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

where ${file} is the argument I am passing to the script. Now all I want is to watch the src dir and run the task passing the file that was just saved. If anyone can help with that, I would appreciate.

Thanks